# TNS:could not resolve service name error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am connecting to oracle database through asp.net. My code is running well on server machine but when I try to run it on local machine I am getting TNS error.
My connection Strings are :

```
 <add name="oraclebldb" connectionString="DataSource=SKM.SMEBANK.ORG;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=bldb;Password=bldb;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
    <add name="OraConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=skm;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=bldb;Password=bldb;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

Comment: Have you added the tnsnames file in your local provider folder?

Comment: Dude: 1) start with the the specific ORA error number, 2) Use this guide for troubleshooting: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm

Comment: You mean i have to copy that file from server and add it to local oracle folder??

Comment: Yes, the tnsnames.ora needs to exist on your local machine as well. Its located in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin. Copy it to your local ORACLE_HOME/network/admin and try again

Answer (score 0):

There must be tnsname.ora file in your local machine where you must be having oracle client installed.

go to

localdrive:\oracle\product\oracle version\client_1\Network\admin

Note: localdrive must b C or D based on location given at the time of installation

or

go to command prompt and type path which will give you the oracle home directory path of your local machine.

See below definition for your reference

```
mydb =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver )(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = mydb)
)
)
```